# Use an ID generated from a button click to access a JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to write a function that allows me to dynamically append content to a modal upon a button click.  The function takes the ID of the button that was clicked, then I wanted it to use that ID to access a JSON object to extract information to be put into a modal.  I was trying to use indexOf to get the index of the JSON object of interest, but its returning an index of -1.  I am quite stuck.  Please help!

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

getIdMoreInfo();

  function getIdMoreInfo(){
    $(".more-info").on("click",function(){
      var exerciseId = $(this).attr("id");
      console.log(exerciseId);
      $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
        dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
        });
      $.each(workoutInfo.id, function(){
        var indexOfId = workoutInfo.id.indexOf(exerciseId);
        console.log(exerciseId);
        console.log(workoutInfo.id)
        console.log(indexOfId);

      });

    });
  };

});
```

This is the JSON

```
var workoutInfo = {
"id": [
    {
        "barbellTricepsExtension": [
            {
                "exercise": "Barbell Triceps Extension"
            },
            {
                "description": "Position barbell overhead with narrow overhand grip. Lower forearm behind upper arm with elbows remaining overhead. Extend forearm overhead. Lower and repeat."
            },
            {
                "equipment": "Barbell"
            },
            {
                "muscles-front": ""
            },
            {
                "muscles-back": ""
            },
            {
                "workout-video-url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2TkTaXagRQ"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "bench-press-narrow-grip": [
            {
                "exercise": "bench-press-narrow-grip"
            },
            {
                "description": "Lay down on a bench, the bar is directly over your eyes, the knees form a slight angle and the feet are firmly on the ground. Hold the bar with a narrow grip (around 20cm.). Lead the weight slowly down till the arms are parallel to the floor (elbow: right angle), press then the bar up. When bringing the bar down, don't let it down on your nipples as with the regular bench pressing, but somewhat lower."
            },
            {
                "equipment": "Barbell, bench"
            },
            {
                "muscles-front": ""
            },
            {
                "muscles-back": ""
            },
            {
                "workout-video-url": ""
            }

        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://www.json.org) but a plain old object.

Comment: Is it possible you can change the format of the object? Having each individual property in its own object within an array of the parent will make it a big pain to work with.

Comment: @Andreas i think JSON is nothing but a sub set of objects only and this particular object meets all the condition which can let this be named as a JSON.

Comment: @void No it's not a subset of objects. JSON is the string representation of an object.

Comment: I'm confused, `workoutInfo.id` is an array of objects, yet you compare those objects against an elements ID ?

Comment: And no, JSON is not automatically the same as a javascript object, it's a dataformat for strings, that happens to *look like* javascript objects, but have other requirements, for instance doublequotes etc.

Comment: @adeneo I am trying to get the ID of a button and pass that ID into my object to access the array of data for each exercise type

Comment: Okay, but the ID will never match an object, you have to devise some sort of search functionality yourself

Comment: @adeneo i got it to work how i want it through by restructuring my object and using some bracket notation. the function gets the element ID and based on that ID returns data specific to that click